# Putting bootstrap tooltip into controler, how is this done?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put bootstrap tooltip into my controller.
But I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function`

I probably need to put more than $srope into the controller, but what?

```
export default function bookController($scope){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    });
}
bookController.$inject = ['$scope']
```

This is how I think it works, or the solution I would like to have.

```
<button ng-click="vm.cancelBooking()">
    <Tooltip placement="bottom" className="in" id="tooltip-bottom">Tooltip bottom</Tooltip>
    CANCEL
</button>
```

This solution is from the website

```
<button ng-click="vm.cancelBooking()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cancel the changes made to the Booking">     
    CANCEL
</button>
```